# How can I replace a supply valve without an upstream shutoff?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I work in a facility. The washer machine supply hose valve needs replaced. There is no accessible shut off for the hot water supply. Without cutting the water to the entire building what can I do

Comment: I wonder how they change out the hot water heater when it goes bad.

Comment: You say there is no accessible valve?  Do you have access to the whole building?  If you need access to a valve you don't have, normally you make arrangements with the building who may need to make arrangements with tenants.  Sometimes full shutoff is indeed necessary and often does not need to be for a significant period of time.  I've seen a plumber cut in a valve with a 5 minute shutoff, which it sounds like would be adequate in your case.  You may want to check out a recent question on freezing water lines for extreme troubleshooting if that or Jack's answer don't serve you.

Comment: You need to schedule hot water downtime with whoever owns the facility. Once this has been scheduled you can calmly add a shut-off valve as needed and replace the hose. Were you hoping for some half-baked suggestion to perform the work with full water pressure? https://youtu.be/OP30okjpCko

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about _Home_ Improvement.

Answer (score 2):

If you're serious about not wanting to shut off the water to the entire building, which you could do at night or off hours, you'll have to work it hot... I mean wet.

Get the right replacement valve, open it up and attach a hose to it that goes outside or to a drain. Disconnect the supply hose from the washer and then, slowly start unscrewing the bad valve. When it comes off, water will start to shoot all over the place. Wrap the pipe with Teflon tape or brush with pipe dope. Quickly put the new valve in place and start to screw it down. The water will now start to run out the new valve and into  the hose and you can tighten up the valve. shut off the new valve and re connect the supply hose.

Comment: Note that it can be extremely difficult to get some types of fitting back on while water is flowing if the fitting includes a constriction.  I've seen a hose bib part we couldn't get back on with 3 decent sized fellas and once you take that part off you're committed, so I would recommend having a shutdown set up and ready as a backup.  The valve for the hose bib shown on the original prints was either forgotten or deleted, so a convenience valve was put in for the outdoor and parkade systems during the shutdown.

Comment: @KH That's why you open the new valve first to reduce/eliminate the constriction....  yes, always have a backup plan.

Comment: I mean an open fitting with a constriction.  The piece we were trying to force back on was technically open, but it didn't take enough pressure off to force it into place.

Comment: also it's hot suppy that's being worked on, there's a risk of burn injuries.

Answer (score 2):

Shut down the cold water supply to the boiler and draining the remaining hot water before replacing parts along the hot water line.